# Teams Compose Extension with only image

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want my compose extension to send just an image but I couldn't do it. I tried the following with only image url:
Thumbnail card (too small image)
Hero card (16:9 adjustment makes it worse)

Also, I couldn't make the grid layout for my extension.

```
        composeExtension: {
            attachmentLayout: 'grid',
            type: 'result',
            attachments: [...]
        }
```

Stills shows the items in list layout.

There is a default button for gifs in Microsoft teams currently. I just want to make a clone of it:
[GIF button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peJbJ.png)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mrsfy: great question. Unfortunately grids aren't supported today in compose extensions, and we reject a card without the other properties. So no, it's not possible currently.